# How do you get rid of empty spaces between y-axis and first bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to graph some bar charts. I do see some empty spaces between first bar and y-axis and the same on the far most right of the bar chart as well. Is there a way to get rid of the empty spaces in ggplot2?

Answer (score 3):

For example like [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3364_d1a578f521174152b46b19d0c83cbe7e.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
p.dia <- ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity))
p + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]